# ArgumentOutOFRangeException when comparing times

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a simple project to use at work (logistics company) for my colleagues and me.

Let me explain a little to make my question a bit easier.

Each Route represents a country that has a deadline. In this example I use Route 114. Route 114 represents the Netherlands and the orders should be finished at xx:xx:xx local time.
I'm using a DateTimePicker so the user can select the deadline and receive a warning if the ProgressBar reaches 70% (in this case a label turns red).

The code I have works so far, but sometimes it throws out an error saying:

**Value of '-4758' is not valid for 'Maximum'. 'Maximum' must be greater
than or equal to 0. Parameter name: Maximum**

I'm an amateur, but it looks like the time is counting backwards in some cases and thus results in a negative Value.

```
    Public Class Deadlines

    Private Route114Deadline As Boolean = False

    Public Function GetTimeDifference(ByVal EndTime As DateTime, ByVal StartTime As DateTime) As Integer
        Dim span As TimeSpan = EndTime.TimeOfDay - StartTime.TimeOfDay
        Dim result As Integer = CInt(span.TotalSeconds)
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub tm114_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tm114.Tick
        ' ROUTE 114 '
        Dim value114 As Integer = pb114.Maximum - GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)
        If value114 > pb114.Maximum Then
            tm114.Stop()
        End If
        If value114 < pb114.Minimum Then
            tm114.Stop()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        pb114.Value = value114
        If Not Route114Deadline AndAlso pb114.Value >= pb114.Maximum * 0.7 Then
            Route114Deadline = True
            lb114.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        pb114.Minimum = 0
        pb114.Maximum = GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)
        tm114.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: An idea for what line it happens on would help.  Timers are not so precise that they go off exactly when set.  Its possible that sometimes they tick off after some keypoint (deadline * .7 ???) resulting in a negative value (ie the time has passed).  You could also probably simplify that using 1 timer @850 ms and evaluate a collection of shipments each time to determine the status

Comment: @Plutonix it usualy happens at these lines: pb113.Value = value113. Depending on the time I insert in the DateTimePickers.

Comment: ...and are we to assume that `pb113` is a `DateTimePicker`?  It is probably what I explained - timers going off a bit late.  Since the timer code is identical, 1 should be enough (maybe refresh to see an edit to first comment)

Comment: `pb113` is the name of the `ProgressBar` I'm using, in this case the Progressbar for Route113. The error occurs on these lines. I updated my question.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with DateTimePickers then (title).  Your code isnt checking to see if the value is less than the pb minumum; you *do* check if it is more than the maximum to turn off the timer

Comment: So I assume I have to check if the PB minimum is smaller then the value and then turn of my timer?

Comment: Yes you have to allow that the deadline (interim or otherwise) has passed.  Since you are working off seconds, it would not take much for the tick to happen afterwards.  what is the value for the timer intervals?

Comment: Updated my question. The error is now solved because the timer will stop if it has a negative value. But why do I get a negative value when comparing two times? The timer won't even start now because it has a negative value from the beginning. How do I let them compare forward in time?

Comment: you should examine the values in the debugger when it crashes to see what is happening; note that in the Load event you set all the PBs to the same Max; then later evaluate against a *different* DTP.  Also, as a DTP (ie UI Control), the user can change the DTP value while you are monitoring and mess up all your calcs (and is why UI controls make horrible variables)

Comment: I added it to a button instead of loading them on startup. When a deadline has passed and I click the button I get this error **Value of '-97' is not valid for 'Maximum'.**

Comment: You're getting a negative because the result is the number of seconds before the end - like a nasa countdown :)  Maybe if you altered the GetTimeDifference function so that it only returns positive values? Or altered the math to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with some help!

```
Public Class Form1
        Private Route114Deadline As Boolean = False

        Public Function GetTimeDifference(ByVal EndTime As DateTime, ByVal StartTime As DateTime) As Integer
            Dim span As TimeSpan = EndTime - StartTime
            Dim result As Integer = CInt(span.TotalSeconds)
            Return result
        End Function

        Private Sub tm114_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tm114.Tick
            ' ROUTE 114 '

            'get the seconds from now to end
            Dim value114 As Integer = GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)

            'check if the seconds are less than 0
            If value114 < 0 Then
                tm114.Stop() 'stop the timer
                pb114.Value = 0 'set the progressbar to 0 just in case the last value was 1 second and is now less than 1
                MessageBox.Show("Time for (114) is up!!!") 'show a message or change the text of a label to allert that time is up
                Exit Sub
            End If

            pb114.Value = value114 'set the progressbar to new amount of seconds

            If Not Route114Deadline AndAlso pb114.Value <= pb114.Maximum * 0.7 Then
                Route114Deadline = True
                lb114.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            'get the number of seconds from now to end
            Dim secs As Integer = GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)

            'make sure there is at least 1 second before setting the progressbar maximum and starting the timer
            If secs > 0 Then
                pb114.Maximum = secs
                tm114.Interval = 500
                tm114.Start()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("The chosen deadline time has already passed")
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```